# Linking OpenCV fails with LNK 2019 unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, opencv3.0

I know, that there are still some requests concerning that toppic, but I think I did everything, writen there. I just downloaded OpenCV but I'm not able to run it.

I did the following: 
**Adding environment variable OPENCV_DIR = ..\opencv\build\x64\vc14** 
**Adding environment variable Path = %OPENCV_DIR%/bin**

**Properties --> C/C++ -> General --> Additional including directories set to ../opencv/build/include**

**Properties --> Linker --> General -->Additional Library Directoies added ../opencv/build/x64/vc14/lib**

**Properties --> Linker --> General --> Additional Library Directories added ../opencv/build/lib/Debug**

**Properties --> Linker --> Input --> Additional Dependencies added:** 

**opencv_calib3d343d.lib 

opencv_core343d.lib 

opencv_features2d343d.lib 

opencv_flann343d.lib 

opencv_highgui343d.lib 

opencv_imgcodecs343d.lib 

opencv_imgproc343d.lib 

opencv_ml343d.lib 

opencv_objdetect343d.lib 

opencv_photo343d.lib 

opencv_shape343d.lib 

opencv_stitching343d.lib 

opencv_superres343d.lib 

opencv_ts343d.lib 

opencv_video343d.lib 

opencv_videoio343d.lib 

opencv_videostab343d.lib 

opencv_world343d.lib**

**Setting CPU Debug to x64**

My code is quite easy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

int main() {
    cv::Mat SrcImg = cv::imread("C:\\HomeC\\Screenshots\\SC_01.bmp", -1);

    std::cout << "Application finished. Press ENTER to exit..." <<     std::endl;
    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

The errors I get are: 
`LNK2019    unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cv::_interlockedExchangeAdd(int *,int)" (?_interlockedExchangeAdd@cv@@YAHPEAHH@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl cv::Mat::release(void)" (?release@Mat@cv@@QEAAXXZ)`

and 
`LNK2019    unresolved external symbol "class cv::Mat __cdecl cv::imread(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int)" (?imread@cv@@YA?AVMat@1@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z) referenced in function main`

So, you can see, I read the documentation and still googled all the stuff about that error concerning OpenCV.

Does anybody has another idea, how to get it run?

Regards,
Jan

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio 2015 or 2017?

Comment: I'm using VS2017

Comment: Ok, I got it - I just deleted and rearanged the project. I think, the problem was, that I also referneced OpenCV via NuGet in the old project. Not its working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now it's working. I had to specifie the folder containing the dlls in the path folder too. I also rearanged the project, as I also referenced OpenCV via NuGet in my old project.